# Invalid field override named 'password'

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I override the `password` field in my `FOS_User` entity, this way:

```
  * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
  *   @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="password",
  *     column=@ORM\Column(
  *       nullable=true
  *     )
  *   )
  * })
```

The `./app/console doctrine:schema:validate` check is fine:

> [Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
>
> [Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.

But when I run the `generate:doctrine:entities` command I get the following error:

> Invalid field override named 'password' for class 'MyAppBundle\Entity\User'.

What is wrong with my setting?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
/**
 * User
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
  *   @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="password",
  *     column=@ORM\Column(
  *       nullable=true
  *     )
  *   )
  * })
 */
class yourUser extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\password()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $password;

    //other code
}
```

be sure to use a recent version of doctrine because override is supported from doctrine version 2.3

Comment: @ORM\password() is not recognized: `[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\password" in property My\AppBundle\Entity\User::$password does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.` I am using Symfony 2.5 and the 'password' annotation is not available in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/